# Keep previous selected value during adding new row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am adding new row to table using jQuery. I have one drop down in row that is bind dynamically using json. now when i am adding row previous row's selected option goes i.e. reset.
I am adding new row using click on button

```
<a href="#" style="margin-top:20px;" id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddNewRow();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Row </a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    Bind();
});

function AddNewRow() {
    var NewRow = ('<tr class="invoicerow">');
    NewRow += ('<td class="taskclass"><select class="form-control task" id="city" name="city"></select>');
    NewRow += ('<td class="mondaytext"><input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" data-parsley-trigger="change" required /></td>');
    NewRow += ('<td class="mondaytext"><input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" data-parsley-trigger="change" required /></td>');
    NewRow += ('<td class="mondaytext"><input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" data-parsley-trigger="change" required /></td>');
    NewRow += ('<td class="mondaytext"><input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" data-parsley-trigger="change" required /></td>');
    NewRow += ('<td class="mondaytext"><input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" data-parsley-trigger="change" required /></td>');
    NewRow += ('<td class="mondaytext"><input type="text" id="pincode" class="form-control" name="pincode" data-parsley-trigger="change" required /></td>');
    NewRow += ('</tr>');
    $("#dvtexttable").append(NewRow);     
    Bind();  
};

function Bind() {
    $.getJSON('/TimesheetEntry/TaskList/', function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Select a TaskList</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, finish) {
            items += "<option value='" + finish.Value + "'>" + finish.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $('.task').html(items);
    });
};
```

Here is my code. any help will really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$('.task').html(items);
```

updates *all* the `select`s on the page, not just the one for the new row, recreating the previous `select`s (and so appearing to reset the value).

You need to pass the new row to the `Bind()` function so that it knows which `select` to update

These easiest way to do this is to use `.appendTo` to return the new row as a jquery object.

---

When you use:

```
$("#dvtexttable").append(NewRow)
```

you return `#dvtexttable`, while:

```
$(NewRow).appendTo("#dvtexttable"))
```

will return the new row after it has been added

This gives you:

```
var row = $(NewRow).appendTo("#dvtexttable"));
Bind(row);
```

and

```
function Bind(row) {
    $.getJSON('/TimesheetEntry/TaskList/', function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Select a TaskList</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, finish) {
            items += "<option value='" + finish.Value + "'>" + finish.Text + "</option>";
        });
        // add row here to ensure it only affects the new row
        $('.task', row).html(items);
        // alternate:  row.find(".task").html(items)
    });
};
```